# I am having problems with a transition effect that I am doing on a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to make an effect that when I scroll down around 600px two pictures start on the outside then they move inward, closer together. But when I do it no effect happens.

html:

```
<section id="services" class="services-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="container12" id="scroll">
                    <img src="img/phone.jpg" id="phone">
                    <img src="img/middle.jpg" id="middle">
                    <img src="img/tablet.jpg" id="tablet">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#scroll {
margin-top: 200px;
margin-bottom: 200px;
text-align: center;
}

#scroll img {
position: relative;
}

.animate    {
transition: 2s ease-in0out;
-moz-transition: 2s ease-in0out;
-webkit-transition: 2s ease-in0out;
}

#phone .animate  {
transform: translate(5em,0);
-moz-transition: translate(5em,0);
-webkit-transition(5em,0);  
}

#tablet .animate  {
transform: translate(-10em,0);
-moz-transition: translate(-10em,0);
-webkit-transition(-10em,0); 
}


#phone .animate  {
transform: translate(5em,0);
-moz-transition: translate(5em,0);
-webkit-transition(5em,0);
}

#tablet .animate  {
transform: translate(-10em,0);
-moz-transition: translate(-10em,0);
-webkit-transition(-10em,0); 
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function()    {


$(window).scroll(function(event)    {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y >= 400)   {

        $('#phone').addClass('animate');
        $('#tablet').addClass('animate');

    }

});

});
```

If you are able to help me with this, I would be very happy. Thanks again for helping me.

Comment: RE The question's title: Ending a statement with a question mark is confusing? :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is adding classes to the `#phone` and `#tablet` elements. However, your CSS is written to handle child elements with `.animate` classes. Your CSS should be written like this:

```
#phone.animate  {
transform: translate(5em,0);
-moz-transition: translate(5em,0);
-webkit-transition(5em,0);  
}

#tablet.animate  {
transform: translate(-10em,0);
-moz-transition: translate(-10em,0);
-webkit-transition(-10em,0); 
}

#phone.animate  {
transform: translate(5em,0);
-moz-transition: translate(5em,0);
-webkit-transition(5em,0);
}

#tablet.animate  {
transform: translate(-10em,0);
-moz-transition: translate(-10em,0);
-webkit-transition(-10em,0); 
}
```